# Friend function have no access to struct member declared in class template

Tags: c++, class, struct, friend

Here is the situation:

```
template <class T>
class A {
    struct S {
        /* some data */
    }
    S some_member;
public:
    /* some methods */
    friend bool B (S);
};
 
bool B (S s) { //<-- ERROR "S was not declared in this scope"
    /* do something */
}
```

What should I do, to have the program compiled correctly?

Comment: please also include the error message in the question. Your immediate problem seems to be that you want `A<some_type>::S` not `S`

Comment: You would have a similar problem if `A` weren't a template, so solve that problem first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While writing the function `B`'s  parameter you have to be

1. in the **scope** of the **class template** `A<>`  and,
2. also specify "some type" like `int`(or `float` etc) as shown below:

```
bool B (A<int>::S s) { //<-- Added change here
    
    return true;
}
```

You can use other types as well i have given example for `int`.

Also, you will need to make `S` public and add the missing semicolon `;` after `struct S` definition.

Comment: note that `S` is private and not only because of that the code in your answer isnt all that needs to change on OPs code

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes i thought that was obvious and OP could figure that out by himself/herself. Also, OP has a missing `;` which i have now mentioned at the end of my answer.